# Unable to start cassandra with this errors

Tags: cassandra

When I run cassandra get these errors. What is the problem?

```
WARN  06:01:00 Unable to lock JVM memory (ENOMEM). This can result in part of the JVM being swapped out, especially with mmapped I/O enabled. Increase RLIMIT_MEMLOCK or run Cassandra as root.
INFO  06:01:00 JMX is enabled to receive remote connections on port: 9909
WARN  06:01:00 OpenJDK is not recommended. Please upgrade to the newest Oracle Java release
INFO  06:01:00 Initializing SIGAR library
WARN  06:01:00 Cassandra server running in degraded mode. Is swap disabled? : false,  Address space adequate? : true,  nofile limit adequate? : true, nproc limit adequate? : false
```

Comment: Those are just warnings, not errors.  Do you actually see any errors?  Does the cassandra process terminate?

Comment: yes these are warning , but what is reason?

Answer (score 2):

Cassandra checks for common ways to improve performance. See the following documents that detail the recommended settings/environment:

1. https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/troubleshooting/trblshootInsufficientResources_r.html
2. https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/install/installRecommendSettings.html